# icenReg: length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Tags: r

I am trying to run an interval censored Cox model in R. The icenReg package has a function ic_sp to do this. However, I get an issue when I give it a factor variable as a predictor.

```
data = data.frame(R = c(2, 1, 4, 7, 4, 6, 8, 8, 12, 3),
                  L = c(3, 1, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 3),
                  gender = c("m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "f", "m"))
s = survival::Surv(data$R, data$L, type = 'interval2')
icenReg::ic_sp(s ~ relevel(gender, "f"), model = 'ph', bs_samples = 5, data = data)

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

I've debugged the function and stepped through it. It seems the problem originates at

```
myFit <- new(callText)
```

In the fit_ICPH subfunction because after it complains that

```
Error in fit$model == "ph" : comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

I've tried stepping into this 'new' function, but I am not able to follow it at that point.

Any help would be appreciated! This is all wrapped up in a shiny application, so I'd really prefer not to edit the dataset if possible; both the dataset and formula are reactive.

Strangely, though probably not once I find the solution, if the variable has 3 levels, it works.

```
data = data.frame(R = c(2, 1, 4, 7, 4, 6, 8, 8, 12, 3),
                  L = c(3, 1, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 3),
                  gender = c("m", "a", "f", "m", "m", "f", "a", "m", "f", "m"))
s = survival::Surv(data$R, data$L, type = 'interval2')
icenReg::ic_sp(s ~ relevel(gender, "f"), model = 'ph', bs_samples = 5, data = data)
> results...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because of the `relevel` call inside of the formula. I will look into allowing this in the future (this is the author of icenReg).

A workaround is to merely relevel your data outside of the function call. For example, the following will work fine:

```
# Same data as above, 
# but changing L to be left side of interval, R as right side
data = data.frame(L = c(2, 1, 4, 7, 4, 6, 8, 8, 12, 3),
              R = c(3, 1, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 3),
              gender = c("m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "f", "m"))

# Releveling the code outside formula
data$gender_f <- relevel(data$gender, 'f')

# Fitting model using cbind syntax
icenReg::ic_sp(cbind(L, R) ~ gender_f, model = 'ph', bs_samples = 5, data = data)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I could get away without modifying the dataset. Any idea why it would work with three levels though? And confusingly the project I'm working on uses R to denote a right censor point and L left censor point, which I why I switch mine.

Comment: @Nick (replaced earlier comment now that I've dug in a little more). The issue three+ levels working makes sense: basically, if there was only two factors, the data matrix ends up as a vector, and I needed a custom method for extracting column names. My custom method did not account for the fact that there could be a function on the right hand side of the formula. With three+ factors, the resulting data matrix is a matrix (because the three levels get expanded into two columns). Likewise, if you have a factor with two levels plus another covariate, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Nick, also will have a patch for this issue soon.

Comment: @Nick: a patch has been pushed to [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/pistacliffcho/icenReg_devel/tree/master/Code). Given that this is a fairly minor bug (only occurs with calling a function with a single covariate with only 2 levels), will probably hold off on pushing to CRAN until bigger updates are made.